# facebook offline_access_token truncating expiry time

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-authentication

I have a question regarding to Facebook removing of offline_access_tokens. According to [the document](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/),we can

> refresh the life time of the token to 60 days after getting a new
>   token

from the facebook.

Just one thing. According to facebook,

> After the offline_access removal date, currently set for 7/5/2012 (see
>   roadmap for exact date), all existing offline_access access_tokens
>   will have their expiration time truncated to 60 days. This truncation
>   will be transparent to the user and your app will continue functioning
>   normally; Facebook will send an updated message through the weekly
>   developer round-up when this truncation will occur.

So, all exisiting offline_access_tokens will be truncated their life time to 60 days from 5 July 2012. **

**Is it safe to assume that the expiry time of existing offline access tokens will be around 3 Sep 2012?**

**

Because for the newly generated token, when I refresh it, I can get the info like below.

> access_token=xxxx&expires=xxxxx

But for the exisiting long lived access token, whenever I refresh it, I can only get the info like below without expires information.

> access_token=xxxx

*Without expire information, I can't nofiy the user ahead to log in to facebook to use the app before the expire time.*

So, like I mentioned above, is it safe to assume that the truncated expiry time of exisitng offline_access_tokens will be 60 days from 5,July 2012?

Edited: **Is there any way to get info provided by https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, where  we can get issued date, etc?** (might be duplicated of this [one](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9236445/is-there-an-api-equivalent-of-the-facebook-access-token-linter-debugger).)

Pls share me your ideas. Thanks ahead.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? If yes, then can you update? I am in the same boat trying to interpret the truncation of existing tokens.